# I want to take input as "Iphone 6s", "iphone", "35000.0" in a single line but i got java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I want to take input as "Iphone 6s", "iphone", "35000.0" in a single line but i got java.util.InputMismatchException. In below code, in third line i am getting error when i am passing value of String ,String ,double type to a method.

```
            System.out.println("Enter modelname,companyname and price");
            Mobile[] mb1 = new Mobile[1];
            mb1[0] = new Mobile(sc.nextLine(),sc.nextLine(),sc.nextDouble());
            test.add1(mb1);
```

Comment: Full exception message _with_ stacktrace would be helpful. Also, is this your only input during program execution or was there something before it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please read. Also, what is a `Mobile` object? Why are you making an array with only 1 element?

Comment: "so I guess we should wait for response from OP." It's too common that the OP simply never responds, I learned that long ago. (Tom deleted one of their comments...)

Comment: @FailingCoder That's right, so we may never know what the actual cause for the issue is. Your answer for example is rather general and is missing a few error cases, but that's understandable due to the missing info. (I deleted the old comment, because the "let's wait for OP" doesn't work anymore when you already posted an answer ;P)

Answer (score 0):

Your input (from java.util.Scanner) takes 2 Strings, and then a float.

Your `java.util.InputMismatchException` shows that your `Scanner.nextFloat()` call is collecting unexpected input, that isn't a number or doesn't meet the criteria that the input requires.

For example, `Scanner.nextFloat()` will cause an error for the following input:

```
foo
basically any character that's not from 0-9 (except for periods, which serve as decimal places)
10..
10.0.
..1
1_000
```

But these are okay.

```
10.
.1
1000
10.1
1942285930580465743673490674390867430698903609346397643069436990
```

Answer (score -1):

`nextLine()` takes the full input line in one shot. What I believe you want is to use instead is `next()`, that only takes the next word. (For the float, you can keep using `nextFloat()`).

Comment: Let's assume it is true that OP whats all three values in one line and read from there, wouldn't the question be different? Wouldn't he ask why the program is still waiting for him to write something, although he already gave three values?